# Временная эффективность JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли, что эффективность первой функции O(n), а второй O(n^2) и их совместная O(n^2)?

```js
function permute(arr) {
  let ch;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ch = arr.splice(i, 1)[0];
    used.push(ch);
    if (arr.length == 0) {
      perm.push(used.slice());
    }
    permute(arr);
    arr.splice(i, 0, ch);
    used.pop();
  }
  return perm
};



function combination(arr, k){
    let res = [];
    for(let i=0; i<n - k+1; i++){
        for(let j=i+1; j<n; j++)
            res.push([arr[i], arr[j]])
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Неверно. В первой функции есть рекурсия, и, соответственно, ее сложность будет `O(N + (N-1) + ... + 1) ≃ O(N(N-1)/2) ≃ O(N^2)`.

Comment: Где объявлена переменная `perm`?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а переменная perm является глобальной и объявлена вне цикла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `permute` порождает все перестановки массива `arr`. Код с комментариям по сложности:

```
/* T(N)    */ function permute(arr) {
/*         */   let ch;
/* N       */   for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
/* N^2     */     ch = arr.splice(i, 1)[0];
/* N       */     used.push(ch);
/* N       */     if (arr.length == 0) {
/* N       */       perm.push(used.slice());
/*         */     }
/* NT(N-1) */     permute(arr);
/* N^2     */     arr.splice(i, 0, ch);
/* N       */     used.pop();
/*         */   }
/* 1       */   return perm
/*         */ };
```

Через `T(N)` обозначено время работы функции `permute`. `N` - длина массива `arr`. Цикл `for` работает за время `N` - это из руководства по JavaScript.

Один вызов `splice` требует времени `N` - когда удаляется или вставляется элемент, хвост массива надо сместить на одну позицию, что требует времени. Кроме того каждая строка со `splice` исполняется `N` раз. Перемножаем - `N^2`.

`used.push`, `used.pop` выполняются за константу (за одну единицу времени). Вызываются `N` раз в цикле. Тоже верно для `if`.

`perm.push` - константа. `used.slice` - `N`: копирование массива длины `N`. Умножать на `N` -  число итераций их не нужно. Благодаря `if` они выполняются только один раз.

`permute` вызывается для массива длины `N-1`: `T(N-1)`. Вызывается он `N` раз.

Общая формула для сложности `T(N) = N + N^2 + N + N + N + NT(N-1) + N^2 + N + 1`. Так как мы работаем в терминах "О-большого", то формула своебразно упрощается: `T(N-1) = N^2 + TN(N-1)`. Все коэффициенты заменяются на единицы. Все функции которые растут медленнее самой быстрой (`N^2`) убираются.

Отдельно надо оценить `T(1)`. Он будет равен `N` - длине массива `used` в этот момент.

Раскроем рекуррентную формулу:

```
T(N) = N^2 + NT(N-1) =
= N^2 + N((N-1)^2 + (N-1)T(N-2)) = 
= N^2 + N(N-1)^2 + N(N-1)T(N-2) = 
= N^2 + N(N-1)^2 + N(N-1)((N-2)^2 + (N-2)T(N-3)) =
= N^2 + N(N-1)^2 + N(N-1)(N-2)^2 + N(N-1)(N-2)T(N-3) =
...
= [N^2 + N(N-1)^2 + N(N-1)(N-2)^2 + ... + N(N-1)(N-2)...3*2*1^2] + N!T(1) <= 
<= [N! + ... + N!] + N * N! = 
= N * N! + N * N! = 
= N * N!
```

Там где неравенство - это оценка сверху. Особенности "О-большого" позволяют написать что в итоге `T(N) = N * N!`.

Ту же самую оценку можно получить более грубо таким рассуждением: время работы алгоритма не может быть меньше чем объём его результата. Это интуитивно очевидно: один элемент результата требует для вычисления и записи не меньше одной единицы времени. Объём результата `N * N!`: первый сомножитель длина одной перестановки, второй - число перестановок. Следовательно **любая** процедура порождающая перестановки работает за `N * N!` или дольше. Предыдущее рассуждение получает эту формулу уже не как оценку, а как точный результат.

Comment: Ух-ты) На первый взгляд кажется, что квадрат. Жесть какая)

Comment: @vp_arth, уж конечно не квадрат. Нельзя такую кучу данных получить так быстро.

Comment: Это если уже понять, что собственно делает функция, второй взгляд)

Comment: Это учтено. Для сплайсов `N^2` именно потому что они линейные. С другой стороны, кого это волнует?  Слагаемое `NT(N-1)` смотрит на всех этих пигмеев и посмеивается.

Comment: Я уже понял это, спасибо. В ответе всё хорошо расписано.

Comment: Круто, отличный ответ!